# Search engine with ability to search for exact match over multiple views?

Tags: database, search, hash, lucene, search-engine

Suppose I have a bunch of raw text, on which I want to perform search.

```
Example:  "* escaped", or "president of the United States".
```

As I have searched there many tools that can do this (e.g. Lucene) by indexing many possible n-grams.

Suppose In addition to the raw text (view 1) somehow I create another view by assigning each word to a lebel = {A, B} which is another view of the raw text (view 2). For example, if there is a document containing:

```
View1 = "Jack killed John because he doesn't know how to code"
```

We have the view 2, exactly for each word:

```
View2 = "A    B      A      B     A   A      B    A   A   B"
```

(In general I might have more views, but let's say we have two view)

Given the second view, I want to be able to search for combination of the two views.

For example:

```
"A of the United States" 

"president of the B"
```

Or perhaps explicitly specified:

```
"V2={A} V1={of the United States" 

"V1={president of the} V2={B}"
```

Are there any similar capabilities in the existing search engines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BlackLab does what I was looking for, although not sure how it is working: 
https://github.com/INL/BlackLab